# Are all 4-regular Hamiltonian graphs Euler graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path, eulerian-path

This is a true/false question I'm trying to solve to prepare for my exam.
Could someone confirm my answer?

What I think:
true, because the graph then has only even degrees and the graph is also cohesive (because of Hamilton cyclus).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but this follows from the fact that every vertex has even degree i.e., the graph is $4$-regular, and that the graph is *connected*, from the fact that the graph is Hamiltonian. [All that is needed is every vertex even degree and the graph is connected.]

Comment: Thank you. But a 4-regular graph could also consist of two parts (i.e. not cohesive) right so that the graph is not necessary Eulerian?

Comment: You are right, I should have said connectivity is what is needed. I will edit my answer.

Comment: If I'm right, every Hamilton graph and every Euler graph has connectivity (i.e. is cohesive)?

Comment: Yes, a graph that is Hamiltonian is indeed connected.